# log USB connect and disconnect in ubuntu 13.x

Tags: usb, usb-drive, log, mass-storage

is it possible to log USB connect and disconnect in ubuntu 13.x? Also it will be excellent if it could log the connect/disconnect and email to some email address. Is there any program for that?

Is it possible with some scripting ? If yes please let me have an idea of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to log, in fact is it already logged by the kernel as standard.
And you can access it from both the dmesg and the system log. `dmesg` and `cat /var/log/syslog`. Be aware this will also send you email on reboot and startup of the system.

Wish you good luck and have fun tweaking it to perfectly suit your needs.

```
#/etc/udev/rules.d/98-usb-udev.rules
#
# Home crafted udev usb mail rule
#
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/home/yourusername/sendudev.sh"
ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/home/yourusername/sendudev.sh"
```

-

```
#/home/yourusername/sendudev.sh
#!/bin/bash
text="$(/bin/dmesg | /bin/grep -i 'usb' | tac)"
/bin/echo -e "Date:$(date)\n\nudev env and reversed log is embed.\n\n$(env)\n\n$text" | /usr/bin/mail -s 'Mail from udev.' -t root@localhost
```

-

```
sudo chmod +x /home/yourusername/sendudev.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. let me try and i will post any difficulties. i am a Linux starter.